# Discord.py bot dont have certificate

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

Yesterday I made a bot and everything was working, today when I try to run my code I have this error:

> ClientConnectorCertificateError(aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError:
>   Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True
>   [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)')]

I am using win10, python 3.8, and pycharm. 
I saw a similar problem on StackOverflow but the solution Is not working for me.

Comment: In your python installation you should have a file named "Install Certificates.command", run that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a virtual environment in Anaconda and adding it as an interpreter in Pycharm.

## Creation of the environment

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.8 anaconda
```

[Documentation of conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands):

-n test_env sets the name of the environment to test_env

python=3.8 anaconda says that you want to use in this environment python in version 3.8. You can put there all the things you need, separated with spaces, e.g. `sqlite` `matplotlib` `requests` and specify their versions the same way as for python.

## Activation

```
conda activate test_env
```

## Deactivation

```
conda deactivate
```

## Getting rid of it

```
conda remove -n test_env --all
```

## Add env to pycharm

1.In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Project  | Project Interpreter. Click the The Configure project interpreter icon and select Add.

In the left-hand pane of the Add Python Interpreter dialog, select Virtualenv Environment. The following actions depend on whether the virtual environment existed before.

[image]
[here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)
Please check this github issue [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423#issuecomment-272093801).

> Basically navigate to your `Applications/Python 3.8/` folder and double
>   click the `Install Certificates.command`.

Try running this same program on 3.8 and run the install certificates command.

You can directly run below instruction in conda prompt or terminal:

```
pip install certifi
```

Or download [this](https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3) script and run it.

Comment: what is `Applications/Python 3.8/` folder? I cant find it, I was looking everywhere for this install certificates but I cant find it. help

Comment: You can run `pip install certifi` on terminal or cmd prompt, or run this code:https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3

Comment: When I run this code I have message:
`-- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in f:\_pythonprojekty_\discordbot\venv\lib\site-packages (2020.4.5.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/_PythonProjekty_/untitled/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/_PythonProjekty_/untitled/test.py", line 24, in main
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Cant find this file: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\SSL'`
When running in cmd I have message: Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: It seems you are using windows: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application or C:\Users\<username>\AppData\application about your exception please put your download file and code in the same directory

Comment: I have everything installed and consistent, but problem with certificate still exist.
For now I will give up and end my project, meaby I will try to make something more simple then discord bot

Comment: Could you create a virtual environment in Anaconda and adding it as an interpreter in Pycharm?

Answer (score 13):

For Mac Users, If they are facing the same problem, You can do the following :-

1. Go to MacintoshHD -> Applications -> Python3.x Folder.
2. Double click on the "Install Certificates.command".

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem and found a solution that worked for me from a youtube comment, basically you can solve this problem by adding a certificate manually.

Sectigo (cert vendor) provides a download link of cert manually:
https://crt.sh/?id=2835394
<- gotten from the link below
You should find at the bottom left corner, where its saying Download Certificate: PEM

(If you can't find it: https://beans-took-my-kids.reeee.ee/38qB2n.png
)

[You have to setup certificate yourself](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome)