# Discord bot not "connecting"?

Tags: python, ssl, discord, discord.py

I am running on python 3.8, with MacOS Big Sur.
When I run some simple Discord bot code, I get a long error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:****)')]
>>>
```

I have Install certificates.command, but this is still happening. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall certifi, and use the `--user` after the command. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate?rq=1) or [this one](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159#issuecomment-640107584), they have worked for lots of people. My guess is that the certificate your using is out-of-date. try reinstalling it.

Comment: ```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```
is what i get and i don't get what --user is supposed to mean.