# Discord.py not working when doing client.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've installed discord.py and I have verified that it is the newest version (1.6.0) however once I run the simple code of just running the bot, I get a long string of errors.
The code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run("***")
```

The errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yasharnishaburi/Desktop/PokeBot/BaiduBot2.py", line 4, in <module>
    client.run("***")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

I've replaced the token in the code and error with stars for obvious reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py bot dont have certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue for discord.py and a solution has been posted on Github regarding this.

Github Issue Link: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159