# Certificate Verification Error 1123 discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have tried to make a simple discord but but i am getting this error

```
ClientConnectorCertificateError(aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True[SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certific
```

Heres my code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('token')
```

*token is my discord token*

I have tried to upgrade certifi and discord.py
and searched stack overflow and the issues page in discord.pys github repo

Plz help

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to figure out what the issue is with hardly any information. Can you edit your question to include relevant code snippets and the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108183/discord-py-bot-dont-have-certificate

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: What is anaconda and conda

Comment: i am on mac os.

Comment: Try running `install Certificate.command` in your python directory. Or go to the Applications folder and then to your python folder, and click on the install certificate file.

Comment: i get a permisiion eroor it tells me to try --user but when i do it the output is same

Comment: should i use my macs admins acount

Comment: Yes, just use sudo

Comment: i will be able to use the admin tommorow

Comment: Alright, LMK how it goes when you do. :)

Comment: OK so my admin said to stay as far away as pssible from certificates stuff and to find any other option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use discord.Client instead of commands.bot. I got this error too and that was the only solution that worked fine.